# Android - GCM server key is not working with Urban Airship

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I am trying to integrate Urban Airship Push notification service in my android project.I have created a new project in google developer console and created a GCM server key.I added that GCM key in Urban Airship configuration as well,but it fails to send the notification.

The Urban Airship Error Console throws an error like

```
Received push with invalid authorization on platform GCM error message
```

I already created a test project in google developer console 2 months back, and having a valid GCM key. If I integrate this key in UA it works fine. But If I create a new server key in same project that is not working.

[image: Google project screen shot]

*API key 4* is recently created but it is not working the Server Key created on June 9th works fine. Is this because the key is auto generated? If that is the issue, how do I auto-create the GCM server key?

Recently, I heard that GCM is migrating to Firebase. Do I need to use FCM key instead of GCM?

Comment: Seems that Google is no longer authorizing the API Keys created by Google API Console. I had a similar issue with Amazon SNS, and managed to fix it by using the Firebase auto-generated server key.

Comment: @tomacco works fine,thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that Google is no longer authorizing the API Keys created by Google API Console. I had a similar issue with Amazon SNS, and managed to fix it by using the Firebase auto-generated server key.

1 - Login into [Google Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), with the same credentials you used for Google API Console.
2 - Create a new project (or import an existing one).
3 - Click on the gear icon and select `Project Settings`

[image]

4 - Select `CLOUD MESSAGING` tab.

There you will see both the API Server Key and the Project number (which is needed in the application). This API Server key is the one you need to introduce in the Push Provider console (Urban Airship in your case).