# Android Device is not receiving Urban Airship Push Notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com, google-developers-console

I am stuck on Urban Airship these past 3 days. I have tried the application in both modes : **Development** & **Production**.

I have configured all the required keys in `airshipconfig.properties` files. I'm still not receiving GCM notifications in Android devices. **Channel ID** has been created successfully.

When I send a message from the Urban Airship site, the message is not received. After that, I check the Error Console on Urban Airship and it is giving this error:

```
Received push with invalid authorization on platform GCM in urbanairship.
```

I checked in Google Console, but now there is no option for Server Key. Now there is a **Restrict option**. If I go for restrict option, then it asks for an IP Address. I don't know what IP Address is required for Urban Airship push notifications.

I have crossed check my application several times. Is there something wrong due to the change in the dashboard of Google console few days back?

Please help me to figure this out. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: There is now a visible note in the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) saying:

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging) tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing configuration.

---

From their [Urban Airship docs](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/push-providers/gcm.html), they aren't specifying any IP, but I would still suggest contacting Urban Airship for a server IP Address that you can add in the restrictions.

If it still doesn't work after adding the Urban Airship server IP address, test by generating a new Server Key, then add the same IP address from Urban Airship. If it still doesn't work from there, I suggest contacting GCM Support Team by filling out this [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support), if you haven't contacted them yet.

---

On a side note, I think the reason for the change in the Google Developers Console is to **encourage the security** for API Keys (Server Key) ***against unauthorized use and quota theft*** (*as can be seen in the API Key if it has no restrictions*).

Comment: Hi i have raised my concern on urban airship support. I also write for IP Address & as well as i will write to GCM Support & Let you know. Thanks

Comment: Might be something with GCM dashboard. Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39493667/1637562 We are in the process of updating our docs.

Comment: @ralepinski Thanks for pointing that out. Guess we can flag this as a possible duplicate.

Comment: I just noticed. The answer from post is suggesting to create/import a project to Firebase first, then use the auto-generated Server Key from there. I'm not sure if that's a good workaround.